# I want to compare 3 SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I created three tables Table1, Table2 and Table3.

- In **Table1** I have 3 columns `Code`, `Name` & `Cityid`
- In **Table2** I have 2 columns `Code` & `Name`
- In **Table3** I have 2 columns `Code` & `Cityid`

In these first I have to compare `Table1.Name` to `Table2.Name`.

If that condition satisfies, take `Table2.Code` and compare it to `Table3.Code`, then take `Table3.Cityid` and compare it to `Table1.Cityid`.

If all conditions were satisfied, insert `Table2.Code` into `Table1.Code`.

please anyone help me in writing query i am to  new sql.

Thanks in advance.

please refer the input sample data

table1
|name         |code     |cityid|
|-------------|---------|------|
|Ersan        |NULL     | 1    |
|Plovdiv      |NULL     | 3    |

table2
|name         |code     |
|-------------|---------|
|Ersan        |401065   |
|Ersan        |401065   |
|Plovdiv      |143967   |
|Plovdiv      |143967   |
|Plovdiv      |143967   |

table3
|cityid   |code     |
|---------|---------|
|1        |401065   |
|3        |143967   |

and output would be like this:

table1
|name         |code     |cityid|
|-------------|---------|------|
|Ersan        |401065   | 1    |
|Plovdiv      |143967   | 3    |

Comment: Without any sample data it is really hard to follow what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry for that ,just now i added an image of sample data .please refer that .Thankyou

Comment: Adding sample data as an image isn't very helpful. Please try to add the sample data in textual format, as it is easier this way to make use of the data.

Answer (score 0):

look i have created sample data like below

table__1 will be

```
code    name    city
0001    a        p
002     b       c1
003     c       c2
004     d       c4
005     e       c5
006     f       c6
007     g       c7
008     h       c8
009     i       c9
```

table__2 will be

```
   code name    city
    0001    a       p
    002     b      c1
    003     c      c2
    004     d      c4
    005     e      c5
    006     f      c6
    007 wrongname  c7
  wrongcode h      c8
    009     i   wrongcity
```

now query for insert record will be

```
insert into table__3
select table__1.code,table__1.name,table__1.city 
from table__2 inner join table__1 
on table__2.name=table__1.name and table__2.code=table__1.code and table__2.city=table__1.city
```

if having any issues comment below... 
best luck...

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn,t work for me . please refer for sample data in my post. I need to insert code in table1 where table1.name= table2.name. If this condition satisfied take table2.code and compare in table.code . If second condition also satisfied  take table3.cityid and compare it with table1.cityId  then insert table2.code in table1.code

Comment: and add expected output as well